# Weird command in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can anyone explain this command?

```
CMD [ -d "node_modules" ] && npm run start || npm ci && npm run start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a directory named `node_modules` exists, then run `npm run start`. Else run `npm ci` and then `npm run start`.

The objective is to only run `npm ci` if node_modules doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Basically -d tests for directory existence and runs `npm run start`, otherwise it will run `npm ci && npm run start`